# Linq IEnumerable Concat not working for list of objects containing second list as child object

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

```
public class Parent
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public List<Child> Children { get; set; }
}

public class Child
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

I have

```
IEnumerable<Parent> parent= items1;
IEnumerable<Child> child= items2;
```

Trying

```
parent.Concat(child);
```

Its returning parent instances only. I want merge list of parent and child, weather it exist in parent hierarchy or not.

Comment: You can't concat lists of different types.

Comment: `Concat()` returns a new list. What do you want that list to contain?

Comment: Consider both have same types, but child elements exist in hierachy

Comment: @CodeCaster Sometimes, smallest thing make you fool. But really Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure? I created the following classes, and my output produced the expected items:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("({0}) {1}", this.Id, this.Name);
    }
}

public class Child : Person
{
    public int Grade { get; set; }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format("({0}) {1} - {2}", this.Id, this.Name, this.Grade);
    }
}

public static void Main()
{
    IEnumerable<Person> persons = Enumerable.Range(0, 3).Select(i => new Person()
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = "Person " + i.ToString(),
    });
    IEnumerable<Child> children = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(i => new Child()
    {
        Id = i,
        Name = "Child " + i.ToString(),
        Grade = i+6,
    });

    foreach (var x in persons.Concat(children))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Running the program produced the following output:

(0) Person 0
(1) Person 1
(2) Person 2
(0) Child 0 - 6
(1) Child 1 - 7
(2) Child 2 - 8
(3) Child 3 - 9

Be aware though, that although the concatenation contains the original items, so both parents and children, the iterator only knows the Person functions. None of the Child functions can be called, unless you first check if it is a child and cast it to a child.

As the example program shows, this is not needed for virtual functions, as the virtual function is a Person function. The implementation of the actual object is called: when it is a Child, the child's function is called. This is the normal behaviour of virtual functions.

Comment: Sorry, My mistake "I was not assigning the result of concat in a variable." So it was my mistake.